# Validate HTML5 Numeric Input Before Sending up to Server

Tags: html, validation, jsp, input, numeric

I'm writing a web based application that does calculations. Instead of the user filling out a form on a JSP and then getting the results on another JSP, I want to have an HTML page using HTML5 to ask the user for numeric input and then display the calculated output on a JSP. Is there any server side method to verify the user entered only numeric information? So far I used used 3 HTML5 input boxes like:
 `<input type="number" name="width" min=".1" step=".1" max="500">`

It appears the only validation it does is catch if the user enters numeric input under the min value or over the max value. If nothing is entered it still sends. I want it to not let you send the data unless all 3 boxes are valid. I know you can simply use JavaScript for this but it's a JSP class so my instructor wouldn't like if I use anything other than HTML or JSP. Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Here's the page they will get prompted with:

`<form method="get" action="carpetprice.jsp">
                        Width of room in feet: <input type="number" name="width" min=".1" step=".1" max="500"><br />
                        Length of room in feet: <input type="number" name="length" min=".1" step=".1" max="500"><br />
                        Price of carpet per square foot: <input type="number" name="width" min=".1" step=".1" max="500"><br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Compute Carpet Price">
                        </form>`

I dont want it to send any of the data to "carpetprice" until it has been fully validated.

Comment: Since JSP is on the server, if validation is done using it the data must have already been sent to the server. Now what exactly are you trying to validate and in what sense? Is it you want an integer and to diss-allow blanks?

Comment: Yes. Like my min and max values are, I would just like values within .1 - 500. Anything else i don't want to get sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

On the page you have the form you need actually need a `<form>` tag. You should show all the code you working with. Here's an example:

```
<form method="POST" action="check.jsp">
<input type="number" name="width" min=".1" step=".1" max="500" name="someMeaningfulName" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in check.jsp you would have something like

```
<%
String toBeValidated = request.getParameter("someMeaningfulName");
//rest of the validation process here
%>
```

Use an if statement to check if the integer is in a certain range. You didn't say what you want to happen if the validation fails. Is the user redirected back to the page with the form on it?

Comment: Well that would be going to a server, right? I want to know if it's possible to validate it with just HTML. Sorry if I didn't specify. I might just have to do this in JSP.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking into it and I don't think it is either. I was hoping to get a definite answer.

Comment: Yea JSP is executed on the server, therefore it's not possible.